# Add Stroke to Children as UIElement

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

Is there a way to add a Stroke to Children as UIElement, along with all the other controls etc? A trick maybe?

The Stroke I'm talking about is: System.Windows.Ink.Stroke

What I'm trying is to trick InkCanvas by moving all strokes to from its StrokesCollection to Children so that I'll be able to manage the Z index for all elements.

Comment: Have you tried to create Polylines from the Strokes, by using their StylusPoints and DrawingAttributes properties?

Comment: Awesome idea. Just tried and yes, it works but I lost the other InkCanvas features like erase and scale/resize.